# PL/SQL split string, get last value?

Tags: oracle, plsql

how could one split a string in PL/SQL to get the last value if the pattern look like this? :

'1;2', in this case the value i want would be 2.

Note: the splitter is the character ';' and values are of different length like '1;2 or 123;45678 etc...'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need that in a stored procedure or in plain SQL? (PL/SQL is **only** for stored procedures)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first find the position of ; using,

```
instr(string,';',1,1)
```

Then use `SUBSTR` function to extract the value starting from one more than the value found in previous function.

```
select substr(string,instr(string,';',1,1) + 1) from table;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you explain the 'FROM TABLE' part please? Also, how to store the value in a variable?

Comment: I assume the strings are stored in a table. If you selecting from table then write your appropriate table name.

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT SUBSTR( column_name, 
               INSTR( column_name, ';', -1 ) + 1 )
  FROM table_name
```

should work.  Here is a [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9bfd6/2).

Comment: Great job! Works perfectly

Answer (score 8):

```
regexp_substr(your_string, '[^;]*$')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can use instr with -1 start position and Substr.

```
pos := instr( searchIn, ';', -1, 1)
res := substr(searchIn, pos + 1)
```

This should work, and if not... this is has to do it